# SQL Server 2008 Maximum Data Returned

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that is returning 29400 rows exactly. It's broken up into MANY smaller result sets. The result sets have anywhere from 1 to 1000 rows in each one. There's about 222 result sets.

When I run it as-is, I'm missing the last 10-13 result sets. I got rid of the extra single-row result sets, and I get all of my data returned.

I added one back in that shows up 14-20 times, and I lose my last 6 result sets.

Is there some maximum number of result sets that SQL 2008 can return? So far google hasn't turned up anything.

A brief overview of the stored procedure:

1: Load 174 users and their departments into a temp table

2: create a cursor to go through those 174

3: start cursor

4: execute a stored procedure to return data based on the variables from the cursor

5: select DeptName (one of the single return datasets)

6: when a department changes

7: return a dataset of totals

8: select 'Rollup' (second single return dataset)

9: return a second dataset that is a rollup of data

10: select 'Break in teams' (third single return dataset)

11: Fetch next from the cursor

Comment: How are you running this? in SSMS?  Or is there something programmatic receiving these record sets?  If it's SSMS, there may be a limit in SSMS to how many result sets it can handle.

Comment: I'm running it two different ways. SSMS and through a stored procedure called in VB.Net. Both ways return the same data.

Comment: It was originally VB6, now it's in VB.Net, both have the same issue. I coded it differently for a work around, now I'm just curious as to what these limits are and how to avoid them next time.

Comment: I was re-reading this and thought of something. I originally assumed you were putting all the returned recordsets into one DataSet object as separate DataTable objects.  But that's not what you said.  Are these are all coming through a single connection, single call/batch?  Or are you executing a series of calls to get your 222 recordsets?

Comment: It's all a single call that returns all of the information, breaks each set of records down into a datatable, and then adds them to a dataset in the code.